# How to zip/concat value and list in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I work on a function working with 4 imputs.

To do so, I would like to get a list summarizing these 4 elements. However I have two variables where the data is unique and two variables composed of lists. I can zip the two lists with `arrays_zip`, but I can't get an array list with the 4 elements :

```
+----+----+---------+---------+
| l1 | l2 |   l3    |   l4    |
+----+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | 5  | [1,2,3] | [2,2,2] |
| 2  | 9  | [8,2,7] | [1,7,7] |
| 3  | 3  | [8,4,9] | [5,1,3] |
| 4  | 1  | [5,5,3] | [8,4,3] |
```

What I want to get :

```
+----+----+---------+---------+------------------------------------------+
| l1 | l2 |   l3    |   l4    |                       l5                 |
+----+----+---------+---------+------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 5  | [1,2,3] | [2,2,2] | [[1, 5, 1, 2],[1, 5, 2, 2],[1, 5, 3, 2]] |
| 2  | 9  | [8,2,7] | [1,7,7] | [[2, 9, 8, 1],[2, 9, 2, 7],[2, 9, 7, 7]] |
| 3  | 3  | [8,4,9] | [5,1,3] | [[3, 3, 8, 5],[3 ,3, 4, 1],[3, 3, 9, 3]] |
| 4  | 1  | [5,5,3] | [8,4,3] | [[4, 1, 5, 8],[4, 1, 5, 4],[4, 1, 3, 3]] |
```

My idea was to transform l1 and l2 in list with the l3 size, and apply then the `arrays_zip`. I did,'t found a consistent way to create this list.

As long as I obtained this list of list, I would apply a function as follow:

```
def is_good(data):
  a,b,c,d = data
  return a+b+c+d

is_good_udf = f.udf(lambda x: is_good(x), ArrayType(FloatType()))

spark.udf.register("is_good_udf ", is_good, T.FloatType())
```

My guess would be to build something like this, thanks to @kafels, where for each rows and each list of the list, it applies the function :

```
df.withColumn("tot", f.expr("transform(l5, y -> is_good_udf(y))"))
```

In order to obtain a list of results as `[9, 10, 11]` for the first row for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `expr` function and apply `TRANSFORM`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


df = df.withColumn('l5', f.expr("""TRANSFORM(arrays_zip(l3, l4), el -> array(l1, l2, el.l3, el.l4))"""))

# +---+---+---------+---------+------------------------------------------+
# |l1 |l2 |l3       |l4       |l5                                        |
# +---+---+---------+---------+------------------------------------------+
# |1  |5  |[1, 2, 3]|[2, 2, 2]|[[1, 5, 1, 2], [1, 5, 2, 2], [1, 5, 3, 2]]|
# |2  |9  |[8, 2, 7]|[1, 7, 7]|[[2, 9, 8, 1], [2, 9, 2, 7], [2, 9, 7, 7]]|
# |3  |3  |[8, 4, 9]|[5, 1, 3]|[[3, 3, 8, 5], [3, 3, 4, 1], [3, 3, 9, 3]]|
# |4  |1  |[5, 5, 3]|[8, 4, 3]|[[4, 1, 5, 8], [4, 1, 5, 4], [4, 1, 3, 3]]|
# +---+---+---------+---------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: @AlexGermain Take a look in Databricks [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/data-transformation/higher-order-lambda-functions.html)